# A question related to cardinality and probability

Tags: probability

I have a question attached related to both probability and cardinality. Let me know if my formulation of the problem is non-rigorous or confusing. Any proof or suggestions are appreciated.Thank you all.
The question follows.

Consider a set $I$ consists of $N$ incidents.

$I=\{i_{1},i_{2},...,i_{k},...i_{N}\}$

Each incident has a probability to happen, i.e. incident $i_{k}$ happens with the probability $r_{k}$. Without loss of generality, we assume $r_{1}\geq r_{2}\geq ... \geq r_{k}\geq ... \geq r_{N}$
Given a constant $n<N$, we can have set $I_{1}=\{i_{1},i_{2},...,i_{n}\}$. Apparently, $|I_{1}|=n$ and $I_{1}\subset I$.
Define a mapping $I\to S$ with $S=\{s_{1},s_{2},...,s_{k},...s_{N}\}$
subject to

$
s_{k} = \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 &\mbox{ (Pr=$r_{k}$)} \\
0 &\mbox{ (Pr=$1-r_{k}$)} \\
\end{array} \right.
$

Pick out the incidents with correspond $s$ being 1 to form the set $I_{2}$ , i.e.

$I_{2}=\{i_{m_{1}},i_{m_{2}},...,i_{m_{M}}\} \quad \mbox{and} \quad s_{m_{k}}=1 \quad k=1,2,...,M $

Apparently, $|I_{2}|=M$ and $I_{2}\subset I$. Note that there could be $I_{2}\ne I_{1}$ and $|I_{2}| \ne |I_{1}|$.

The question is,
If we have two set $A$ and $B$ with following assumptions:

(1)$ A\subset I$ and $B\subset I$

(2)$|A|=|B|=n$

(3)$ |A \cap I_{1}| \geq |B \cap I_{1}| $

Is the following statement true?

$ E(|A \cap I_{2}|) \geq E(|B \cap I_{2}|) $

where $E$ means expected value.
If this is true, how to prove it? If not, how to prove it’s not true?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, your problem could be reformulated as follows.
Consider $N$ variables $X_{n}$ each following a Bernouilli law $B(r_{n})$, do we have $\mathbb{E}(\sum_{a\in A}X_{a}) \geqslant \mathbb{E}(\sum_{b\in B}X_{b})$ when $|A\cap I_{1}|\geqslant |B\cap I_{1}|$ (with $I_{1}=\{1,2,3..,n\}, n< N$) ?

The answer is clearly no. Take $N=3$, $n=1$, $r_{1}=r_{2}=0$, $r_{3}=1$, $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{1,3\}$ for example.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But I think in your example you ignore one of my assumptions, which is $r_{1}\geq r_{2} \geq ... \geq r_{k} \geq ... \geq r_{N}$.  Would the answer is still a NO if you consider this?

Comment: Oh yes, I'm sorry I didn't see that ! The answer is still no: take $r_{1}=1$, $r_{2}=1/2$, $r_{3}=1/3$ and intervert $A$ and $B$ in my previous example. The main point is: given two different sets who have the same intersection with $I_{1}$ you can favor the expectation of one or the other by changing the remaining $r_{k}, k > n$.

Comment: Even if the two sets don't have the same intersection with $I_{1}$ you can still do it as long as there are enough $r_{k},k >n$ left.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't understand how your example works. In your example, $E(\Sigma_{a \in A}X_{a})=3/2$ and $E(\Sigma_{b\in B}X_{b})=4/3$ if I understood well.

Comment: And please note that I assume $|A|=|B|=n$ as well as the non-increasing probability. In your example, $|A|=|B|=2$ but $n=1$.

Comment: Maybe I should also add $A\subset I$ and $B\subset I$ to make the problem more clear. Essentially, A and B are both subsets of I but A has no less incidents of top n probabilities than B. I want to see if A has no less incidents than B too when those incidents in I 'realize' based on their Bernouilli law.